# Javafx: update TableCell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a `TableView` and a custom `MyTableCell extends CheckBoxTreeTableCell<MyRow, Boolean>`, In this cell is `@Overridden` the `updateItem` method:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if(!empty){
        MyRow currentRow = geTableRow().getItem();
        Boolean available = currentRow.isAvailable();
        if (!available) {
            setGraphic(null);
        }else{
            setGraphic(super.getGraphic())
        }
    } else {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

I have a `ComboBox<String>` where I have some items, and when I change the value of that combobox I want to set the visibility of the checkboxes depending on selected value. So I have a listener:

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue.equals("A") || newValue.equals("S")) {
            data.stream().filter(row -> row.getName().startsWith(newValue)).forEach(row -> row.setAvailable(false));
        }
    });
```

- The `data` is an `ObservableList<MyRow>`
- This is just an example and a simplified version of my code

When I change the value in comboBox the table's the chekboxes don't disappear until I scroll or click on that cell. There is a "sollution" to call `table.refresh();` but I don't want to refresh the whole table, when I want to refresh just one cell. So I tried to adding some listeners to trigger the updateItem, but I failed at every attempt. Do you have any idea how can I trigger the update mechanism for one cell, not for the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the cell's graphic, instead of just setting it:

```
private Binding<Node> graphicBinding ;

@Override
protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
    graphicProperty().unbind();
    super.updateItem(item, empty) ;

    MyRow currentRow = getTableRow().getItem();

    if (empty) {
        graphicBinding = null ;
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        graphicBinding = Bindings
            .when(currentRow.availableProperty())
            .then(super.getGraphic())
            .otherwise((Node)null);
        graphicProperty.bind(graphicBinding);
    }
}
```

Comment: At the first sight this is a very good solution, but I get `RuntimeExceoption` : a bound value cannot be set at `super.updateItem(...)` at the row : `setGraphic(null)`

Comment: @Sunflame Do you have the `graphicProperty().unbind()` line there? I don't see how you could get that exception with that there.

Comment: Yes, but I solved it by swaping the `graphicProperty().unbind()` with `super.updateItem(...)`, so it's working fine, thank you very much :)